# Get year from find method mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I wrote a function to select one field and i don't know how to receve only year from this.
My function(return object with full date) :

```
module.exports.getProjectYears = function(callback){
    Project.find({},{"create_date":1,"_id":0},callback[]).sort({create_date:-1});
}
```

Comment: Is your date type is Date, in your schema?

Comment: You will have to parse the year out of the date object. Depends how the date object or string is.

Comment: yes my field create_date is a Date type

Answer (score 0):

Try an aggregation query with a project:

```
> db.test.aggregate([{$project:{ create_date_year : {$year: "$create_date"}, _id: 0}}])
{ "create_date_year" : 2018 }
```

This uses $year - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/year/